# Designing for asp.net-mvc Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm about to start a new large mvc 2 project and i guess i should use areas though this is still a grey area (sic) for me.

the site will have several sections such as user maintenance, project maintenance, some sort of dashboard for projects etc.

in the projects are you'll be able to add tasks with attachments etc, move tasks between projects and attach users to tasks.  there's a bit more but you get the idea.

Now i know this sounds like a million other projects and in most ways it is but we have specific requirements.

My question goes to the people that have implemented areas.  How do you decide what should be an area?  How do you plan the project in the first place so that the areas make sense?

would i have an area for project/task maintenance and an area for project dashboards?

i'm kinda stuck on how to begin designing against areas.

Comment: Also, can you share PartialViews across areas?  Say I have a user PV that I'd like to use in company maint area as well as the project maint area

Comment: On the partials views, what I have done is modify the view engine locations for shared views. Any view that can be shared across any area goes to a specific folder (not the default Share Folder) since it can get really full. On the other hand you could just put them in the Shared Views Folder :)